# como replicar el comando egen de stata a r

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una base de datos algo grande y necesito replicar el siguiente codigo de stata a r

```
egen school = mean(aux), by(rbd)
```

intenté utilizar lo siguiente:

```
within(data, {school= ave(aux,rbd)} )
```

pero no me resultó, tambien intente lo siguiente:

```
data %>% 
group_by(rbd) %>% 
mutate(school = mean(aux))
```

y me entrego una columna llena de NA, tanto la variable `aux` como `rbd` son columnas con valores numericos, agradezco de antemano su ayuda

Comment: prueba agregando mean(aux, na.rm = T)

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, tienes que realizar lo que comenta @Bastian. Tienes que agregar el `na.rm=T`

Solo usando R base el código sería el siguiente:

```
within(data, {school= ave(aux,rbd, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))})
```

Y usando `dplyr` seria:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(rbd) %>% mutate(school=mean(aux, na.rm=T))
```